# The Type or namespace could not be found but im using right reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hello im making a website but while writing the controller i faced this error;

"**RepositoryTechBlog could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

I dont face this error only here also in another class(Im trying to access another solution different than RepositoryTechBlog) in the same solution.

Here is my code;

I want to access CategoryRepository in the RepositoryTechBlog but as i said im facing with error above.

```
using System;
using RepositoryTechBlog;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AlperTechBlog.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        CategoryRepository cr = new CategoryRepository();
        InstanceResult<BCategory> result = new InstanceResult<BCategory>();

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            result.resultList = cr.List();
            return View(result.resultList.ProcessResult);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddCategory()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCategory(BCategory model)
        {
            model.category_ID = new int();
            result.resultint = cr.Insert(model);
            ViewBag.Mesaj = result.resultint.UserMessage;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            result.resultT = cr.GetObjById(id);
            return View(result.resultT.ProcessResult);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(BCategory model)
        {
            result.resultint = cr.Update(model);
            ViewBag.Mesaj = result.resultint.UserMessage;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            result.resultint = cr.Delete(id);
            return RedirectToAction("List", new { @mesaj = result.resultint.UserMessage });
        }
    }
}
```

And my category repository if you guys need it;

```
using AlperTechBlog;
using CommonTechBlog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RepositoryTechBlog
{
    public class CategoryRepository : DataRepository<BCategory, int>
    {
        private static BlogDatabaseEntities db = Tools.GetConnection();
        ResultProcess<BCategory> result = new ResultProcess<BCategory>();

        public override Result<int> Insert(BCategory item)
        {
            db.BCategories.Add(item);
            return result.GetResult(db);
        }

        public override Result<int> Delete(int id)
        {
            BCategory deletedItem = db.BCategories.SingleOrDefault(d => d.category_ID == id);
            db.BCategories.Remove(deletedItem);
            return result.GetResult(db);
        }

        private static int GetCategory_ID(BCategory d)
        {
            return d.category_ID;
        }

        public override Result<int> Update(BCategory item)
        {
            BCategory c = db.BCategories.SingleOrDefault(u => u.category_ID == item.category_ID);
            c.category_Name = item.category_Name;
            c.Category_Tag = item.Category_Tag;
            return result.GetResult(db);
        }

        public override Result<List<BCategory>> List()
        {
            List<BCategory> catList = db.BCategories.ToList();
            return result.GetListResult(catList);
        }

        public override Result<BCategory> GetObjById(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Result<List<BCategory>> GetLatestObj(int quantity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I dont only face this error only here also in another class(Im trying to access project different than RepositoryTechBlog) another in the same project. " Eeeeehm, what? Please use adequate grammer and some punctuation. I have absolutely no clue what you´re talking about.

Comment: How did you refer the project of `CategoryRepository` in the project of controller?

Comment: Sorry for bad grammer and punctuation. Im not native English speaker as it seems. With projects i mean solutions

Comment: I refered it as RepositoryTechBlog if that what you ask.

Comment: Is the `CategoryController ` in another project than `CategoryRepository` ? If so, have you added a reference to the other project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks guys i solved the problem it was about the references.

Comment: BTW, you really, really, really **should not use the generic-repository anti-pattern with Entity Framework** - because your `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>` types already provide you with the Unit-of-Work and Repository types respectively - you're creating an abstraction-over-an-abstraction which will only cause problems later on as your project becomes more complex.